# Passing values of contact form to lead event through facebook pixel

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-pixel

I am trying to use the `fbq('track', 'Lead');` when a user submits the contact form on the website. The pageview event works fine, but I want to send out the form data like first and last name, email and contact when the submit button is clicked. Not sure what's wrong

```
<input type="text" id="fname">First name</input>
    
<input type="text" id="lname">Last name</input>
    
<input type="text" id="email">Email</input>
    
<input type="text" id="number">Number</input>
    
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    
       
        let firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
        let lastName = document.querySelector('lname').value;
        let email = document.querySelector('email').value;
        let number = document.querySelector('number').value;
    
    
        fbq('track', 'Lead', {
          content_name: 'Form',
          content_id:email,
          value: number,
        });
      });
```

Comment: The lead event doesn't take Personally Identifiable Information (PII) as input. What are you trying to achieve here?